# send --port argument to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
#!flask/bin/python
import subprocess
import types


from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, abort, request, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/v1/kill/process/<processName>')
def  killProcess(processName):
      pid = subprocess.Popen(["pidof", processName], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      pid = pid.stdout.read()
      if len(pid) != 0:
          for p in pid.decode("utf-8").split(" "):
              p = int(p)
              subprocess.call(["kill","-9", str(p)])
          return make_response(jsonify({'error': False}), 200)
      else:
          return make_response(jsonify({'error': "Service Not Found"}), 400)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8888)
```

I want to run this code like this:

‍‍‍‍`python fileName.py --port 8888`,
How to send --port argument to python and port not hard code.

Comment: side note: edit top line, to have an absolute path (starting with `#!/`), then make it executable with `chmod +x «fileName.py»`. Now you can run it as `./fileName.py`. Now rename to get rid of the `.py`. and you can run as `./fileName` (not exposing implementation).

Comment: You need to look at argument processing. I think (if I remember) that there is a variable `args`. There are libraries that will help you parse this variable, but you don't need then (all depends how complex it gets).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have no problem running the program!!

Comment: that is why I prefixed the comment with `side note:`

Comment: You need to use `sys.argv` to access command line paramters, or if you're feeling funky, use `argparse`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv Also, this is a programming question, not a Unix question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems in your script. But i'm just gonna answer your question.

> The argparse module makes it easy to write user-friendly command-line interfaces. The program defines what arguments it requires, and argparse will figure out how to parse those out of sys.argv. The argparse module also automatically generates help and usage messages and issues errors when users give the program invalid arguments.

[Python argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-p','--port', help='Port_number', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    app.run(debug=True, port=args['port'])
```

args['port'] is a string

Comment: Thanks @pyramid13 jooon, and you can accept my answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

When Python runs the arguments are passed in as the array `sys.argv`.

You can do this in one of two ways. You can use the built-in `argparse` module, or you can directly access the `sys.argv`.

Using `argparse`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run flask program')
parser.add_argument(
    '--port',
    action='store',
    dest='port',
    type=int,
    default=8888,
    metavar='PORTNUM',
    help='set port number')
args = parser.parse_args()


print(args.port)
```

Using the `sys.argv` directly:

```
import os
import sys

port = 8888  # default value
reversed_args = list(reversed(sys.argv[1:]))
while True:
    if not len(reversed_args):
        break
    if reversed_args[-1] == '--port':
        reversed_args.pop()
        if not len(args):
            sys.exit(127)
        path = int(reversed_args.pop())
    else:
        sys.exit(127)

print(port)
```